# Strange R message: Persistent UI failed to open file

Tags: r

I have just updated my R to version 3.1.1 on my Mac machine, and since then have started getting this strange message when running analyses.

```
Persistent UI failed to open file ..../org.R-project.R.savedState/window_2.data: No such file or directory (2)
```

Where I have written the .... there is the rest of the file directory, but I didn't think it necessary to add in.

There does not appear to be anything specific that sets off this error. I am usually running a number of R windows at once - which are running difference analyses (around 6) and the error appears across all windows at roughly the same time I think, I am not usually watching the analyses tick over.

It doesn't kill the analyses. And I haven't found it causing any problems.

I am just curious what it means, and how I should fix it?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I googled *R Persistent UI failed to open file* and it looks like it's a Java/Apple bug.  There are quite a few links about it

Comment: Thanks, I saw there were mentions of it in other scenarios, but nothing relating to R. So I was curious if this had any specific R implications - but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty old, but I just ran in to the same problem.

You see this message because `R` does not have permission to change your `~/Library/Shared Application State` directory.

If you want to change it, **1** just navigate to the folder, **2** right click it, and **3** uncheck the *lock* checkbox or change the permissions to that folder.

I don't mind the `R` error message because I hate OSX writing all the current application states to that folder.