# Eclipse error on Mac when trying to connect Finch robot: Persistent UI failed to open file

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Following is my machine configuration

```
Java Version: 8
Mac OS Version: 10.14.2
Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
```

I'm trying to connect a Finch robot and run a piece of code and I get the following error.

> 2018-12-10 14:32:34.951 java[1697:511537] Persistent UI failed to open
>   file
>   file://localhost/Users/pok/Library/Saved%20Application%20State/net.java.openjdk.cmd.savedState/window_1.data:
>   Permission denied (13)

The same code runs on a windows machine perfectly fine and I'm able to run other Java code in my Mac as well. The error comes when I plug in the Finch. I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394682/strange-r-message-persistent-ui-failed-to-open-file) but the error message doesn't seem to be referring to a folder location. I'm quite new to Mac OS.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permissions to the specified file...

Comment: I'm bit confused. I'm logged in as Admin so then why don't I have permission? Is there a specific way in Mac that I need to specify permission?